Linking a SQL Server database to a Git repository in Azure DevOps with SSMS
Can someone let me if it's actually possible to link or connect a SQL Database to Azure DevOps with SSMS for Version Control.
During my research, I have noticed that it's possible but you are required to purchase some kind of plugin from a 3rd Party. Is it possible to link directly to Azure DevOps Repo directly from SSMS?

@DaleK, thanks for reaching out. Yes, I would like SSMS to commit changes to Azure Repo from a Database

So yeah, as you have noticed thats not possible, because think about it, SSMS is purely a UI, the code is stored in the database not in SSMS, and many people can connect to the same database using any UI they like. And since SSMS isn't a dev environment is doesn't track code changes locally like a dev environment would. So if you want to run any form of version control from SSMS it has to first do a database compare to find what has changed. And to do a database compare it needs a baseline, which is where the tools come in, because they track the changes being made.

You can do version control stuff from a database project in visual studio... because that maintains a baseline... then you have 2 options, either make your changes in VS (cos thats a dev environment) and push them to the actual database (like normal code dev), or you can run a database compare with the baseline and commit the changes... but then you get all changes made since last time. Either way you have the issue that someone could be changing the database directly without following your processes.

So you first gotta design your workflow, then find the tool that will handle that. But the answer to your direct question is "NO".

Visual Studio is extremely cumbersome as means for version control.  Are there any other methods to link a sql database to azure DevOps repos?

Just to be clear, this discussion is off topic for this site, so you risk it being closed. But you need to explain your envisioned workflow in order to suggest something. If you just want to track changes and commit them from time to time (not a very useful workflow but a basic one) then try RedGate.

And to be honest version with SQL Server is a bit cumbersome, regardless of the tools used, if managed at a database level.

@DaleK, on a somewhat unrelatd question, how would you go about implementing change control, or source control/versioning with a SQL Database

The cleanest way I have come across is having the SQL as part of the application code, and then having part of the deployment pipeline run the scripts against the database before deploying code using a tool such as "RoundhousE". The way I do it on another project right now, is I have a Visual Studio database project, which I do a database compare against the development database after having written the SQL I need, I commit those changes, have them reviewed in a PR, then publish them to production.

I have also used the redgate source control tool, which automatically tracks all changes (using triggers) in its own database. This at least gives you a history if you have no other mechanism in place.
